# Configuring Amazon EC2 for a dynamic website

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache2

I am curious about Amazon webservices and so I thought of creating a dynamic webpage with Amazon EC2. I created an instance, installed apache and php and made sure it is working in EC2(using remote access). I have assigned a elastic IP to the instance. My question is how to access the webpage that I created in the instance. I am not sure what to give the servername in httpd.conf. My goal is access the page like `http://amazonaddress/test.php`

I am using windows server, but I think it is basically the same. My documents are in the same folder as mentioned in conf file. But when I use my elastic IP, it isn't working . Not even the basic index page in the apache htdocs(that's the home folder according to conf). To throw more light I will explain what I have done till now.

I have created a micro instance(EC2) and logged into it using remote desktop. I have installed apache msi file and php after that. I have created a elasticIP and attached the instance and to my security group I have added http service to port 80. I have tested if localhost is working in my remote machine(points to index.html). After that I have tried accessing it using elastic IP and it just times out. Is there any step I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

You can access it via `http://255.255.255.255` where you replace the `255.255.255.255` with your elastic IP address.

Then you want to setup DNS for your domain name. So you'll need to create an A Record mapping www.yourdomain.com to whatever your elastic IP address is. You can usually do this via your domain name registrar as most of them also run basic DNS services for free.

Comment: I was not interested in connecting it to a domain name, I was just trying to see if I can access a dynamic webpage through elastic IP.

Comment: You can access it via http://255.255.255.255 where you replace the 255.255.255.255 with your elastic IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You can access an ec2 instance using it's public DNS name (or elastic IP since you already have one of those), which can be seen in the instances description tab. Configuring your personal domain name to point to that server will involve creating an A Record mapping to that public IP.

Assuming apache has been setup correctly, that's all you should need to do to get started (and your test.php page is in `/var/www/`). For your purposes, you probably shouldn't even need to modify the httpd.conf file at all.

Also, be sure to remember to open a port on the security group (under Network & Security from the EC2 Console) that the instance belongs to. In your example, you will want to open port 80 inbound with source `0.0.0.0/0` (unless you want to limit access to a specific IP range).

Hope this helps.